# OpenCV Undefined reference

Tags: android, opencv

I am using opencv C++ code so that i can change some code stuff and compile it and gets the result. The issue is i'm able to use functions of opencv c++ in my JNI interface function. I'm able to use these functions after adding there header's at top of code. When i am running a compilation i'm getting undefined reference error.

I'm doing this for android coding.

The error are given below(Few errors):

```
Volumes/MAC/Farrakh/Software-Setups/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-    
4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-      
androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/opencvtest/native.o: in function   
cv::Mat::release():jni/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:366: error: undefined reference to 
'cv::Mat::deallocate()'

/Volumes/MAC/Farrakh/Software-Setups/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-
4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-
androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/opencvtest/native.o: in function 
Java_com_whizpool_opencvtest_MainActivity_imread_11:jni/native.cpp:14: error: undefined reference 
to 'cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, 
int)'

/Volumes/MAC/Farrakh/Software-Setups/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-
4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux- 
androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/opencvtest/native.o: in function 
Java_com_whizpool_opencvtest_MainActivity_imread_11:jni/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:277: error: 
undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libopencvtest.so] Error 1
```

I tried so many things got from google but i did not get any result.

Below is JNI code that is used to call Opencv C++ code.

```
#include "com_whizpool_opencvtest_MainActivity.h"

#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_whizpool_opencvtest_MainActivity_imread_11(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring string)
{
    const char *w_buf = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, 0);

    Mat imgMat = imread("abc", 0);

    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are linker errors; you need to tell the linker to link against opencv_core and opencv_highgui. You can do this in the makefile or in the build system that creates the makefile for you (if any).